# Why is casting to a generic type slower than an explicit cast in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, closures, anonymous-delegates

I'm building a message dispatch map in C# and mostly just playing around with some different approaches.  I am curious about a performance difference I am measuring, but it's not obvious why from looking at the IL.

The message map:

```
delegate void MessageHandler(Message message);
AddHandler(Type t, MessageHandler handler) 
{ 
    /* add 'handler' to messageMap invocation list */ 
}

delegate void GenericMessageHandler<T>(T message);
AddHandler<T>(GenericMessageHandler<T> handler) where T: Message
{
    AddHandler(typeof(T), e => { handler((T)e); });
}

Dictionary<Type, MessageHandler> messageMap;
```

I then have a class hierarchy of Messages, similar to EventArgs in WPF, for example:

```
public class Message {}
public class VelocityUpdateMessage : Message
```

and observer classes with handler functions:

```
void HandleVelocityUpdate(VelocityUpdateMessage message) { ... }
```

I am measuring 2 ways of adding & invoking handlers.  I am wrapping the delegate call so I can get a bit of conceptual type safety and therein lies the perf difference.

Approach 1:  listener calls

```
AddHandler(typeof(VelocityUpdateMessage), 
           e => { HandleVelocityUpdate((VelocityUpdateMessage)e); });
```

Approach 2:  listener calls

```
AddHandler<VelocityUpdateMessage>(HandleVelocityUpdate);
```

Both approaches build a MessageHandler delegate that makes a cast and the same method call, but calling the delegates built using approach #2 is a wee bit slower even though the generated IL looks identical.  Is it extra runtime overhead in casting to a generic type?  Is it the type constraint?  I would expect the JITted delegates to be the same once the generic type is resolved.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: How are you measuring?  That is extremely important with these micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I had to look at MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray() IL rather than the ILSpy results for the delegates to get to the bottom of this. Using a generic delegate to wrap my message handler and cast the message type generates:

```
0000 : ldarg.0
0001 : ldfld
0006 : ldarg.1
0007 : unbox.any
000C : callvirt void MessageTest.Message+tMessageHandler`1[MessageTest.VelocityUpdateMessage].Invoke(‌​MessageTest.VelocityUpdateMessage) 
0011 : ret
```

where the wrapper delegate with the explicit cast generates:

```
0000 : ldarg.0
0001 : ldarg.1
0002 : castclass
0007 : call void Message.Component.HandleVelocityUpdate(MessageTest.VelocityUpdateMessage)
000C : ret
```

So yes, there is minimal overhead from using generics in this way.

Answer (score 3):

The below line creates a new instance of an anonymous type each time it is called. Could that the cause of your performance difference?

```
AddHandler(typeof(T), e => { handler((T)e); });
```

Comment: The line doesn't contain a `new { ... }`. Where is the anonymous type?

Comment: To clarify, I am seeing the performance difference when calling the delegates (dispatching the messages to the handler), I am not profiling the AddHandler calls since they are setup code.  As Christopher says I will get a new method jitted for each type but my test code is just calling the same handler over and over in a tight loop so the hit for code generation should be just a small blip.  Maybe its more than I think it is.  I'm seeing an elapsed time of ~70ms for 100k calls of #1 vs. ~110ms for #2.  It's not orders of magnitude like calling Delegate.DynamicInvoke.

Comment: It is not an anonymous type, at least not in the formal C# language definition of one.  There is a hidden class that makes the lambda expression work, the *new* expression is hidden as well.  The OP makes the opposite observation though.

Comment: Hans Passant is correct -- that is not an "anonymous type" insofar as it is not a usage of the C# language feature called "anonymous types". It is an anonymous type in the more general sense that it is a compiler-generated type with an "unspeakable" name. We usually call such types "closure classes", or "display classes". (The latter is an unfortunate bit of jargon; the type we generate contains elements that allow the debugger to *display the members of the type as locals rather than fields*, so it is the "display" class.)